# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'save' - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I get this error when I try to save my plot with matplotlib (    plt.save('static/chart.png')). I am sure there is a problem with import but I am not sure what exactly. These are imports I use:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: [savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)

Comment: What if you use `plt.savefig('static/chart.png')` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `save` function in `matplotlib.pyplot`. ׁPerhaps you want to use `savefig`?